# How to fix my cropper modal to show up after choosing the attachment in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problem with my modal `id="cropper_js_banner"` is not showing after clicking the attachment button. This is just part of the code. I just want to know why my `cropper_js_banner` is not showing after clicking the choosing the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing bootstrap, just add this script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/